# numpy array eval representation formula

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to evaluate symbolic expression with np array

example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1]*4)
b = np.array([2]*4)
res = repr(a) + ' + ' + repr(b)
value = eval(res)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'array' is not defined
```

I have a workaround but I will know if I can solve my initial problem

workaround found on stackoverflow [Python eval function with numpy arrays via string input with dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826500/python-eval-function-with-numpy-arrays-via-string-input-with-dictionaries)

```
formula = 'x+y'
res = eval(formula,{'x':a, 'y':b})
```

Edit:

in order to solve the problem add the array definition in the import module

```
from numpy import array
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? `eval` is evil.

Comment: When doing a copy-n-paste from a question I sometimes need to add a `array=np.array` to the interactive session.

Comment: @EricDuminil: i have a symbolic expression and I want a method evaluate which will apply np.array on each variable of my expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Representations are of the form: `array([1, 1, 1, 1])`. So we need an `array` definition imported. So the following should work:

```
from numpy import array
a = array([1] * 4)
b = array([2] * 4)
res = repr(a) + ' + ' + repr(b)
eval(res)
```

Result:

```
array([3, 3, 3, 3])
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt answer, it was the same kind of answer in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750639/how-can-a-string-representation-of-a-numpy-array-be-converted-to-a-numpy-array/35750887
but I had not understood the problem with the array definition

Comment: `eval` is dangerous. I wonder if there's not a better way, e.g. with `sympy`.

Comment: I know sympy but I need the symbolic expression graph to make other more complicated stuff like Theano feature (GPU, OpenMP etc...), so I prefer to not use a whole module just to construct an expression tree